# How to group mongodb aggregate array of objects data To sum numbers on the same date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, group-by, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I'm trying to create charts but I can't combine the data to be like "Expected result below"

What can I use to return "Expected result".

I tried using $group in $group and $reduce and it didn't work well.

I hope someone can help me solve this task

**Current result is**

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5fd4c3586e83b334d97c5218",
      "consumption":5,
      "charts":[
         {
            "date":"2020-10",
            "consumption":1
         },
         {
            "date":"2020-10",
            "consumption":1
         },
         {
            "date":"2020-11",
            "consumption":1
         },
         {
            "date":"2020-11",
            "consumption":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

**Expected result is**

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5fd4c3586e83b334d97c5218",
      "consumption":5,
      "charts":[
         {
            "date":"2020-10",
            "consumption":2
         },
         {
            "date":"2020-11",
            "consumption":2
         },
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go with aggregations

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$charts" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { _id: "$_id", month: "$charts.date.month", year: "$charts.date.year" },
      consumption: { $first: "$consumption" },
      total: { $sum: "$charts.consumption" },
      date: { $first: "$charts.date" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      consumption: { $first: "$consumption" },
      charts: {
        $push: {
          date: "$date",
          consumption: "$total"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q2QFb4_W5IP)**

Comment: Thanks but may you didn't understand me,  what i need is sum all "consumption" with same "Date" NOT only return one date, so let me update 'Current Results' and 'Expected Results' to understand me.

Comment: @MohamedAdelLotfy Its working as you expected.. can you brief me what wrong with the above implementation?

Comment: its not working in updated results, please test current result again in "Mongo playground"

Comment: And please look at the dates in the current result and the expected result

Comment: @MohamedAdelLotfy you can't do a dramatic change in the question, bcs we spent a lot of time to solve the problem. Suddenly you changed the question.. And waste of time at last

Comment: And the above query working fine. Plz check https://mongoplayground.net/p/BCOD-67uenz

Comment: @MohamedAdelLotfy does the answer help you?